# Python print line number in random function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to get the line number from a random line function that reads random lines from a .txt file.
This is the random line function:

```
import random
        def randomline(self, file1):
            with open(file1) as f:
                lines = f.readlines()
                regel = random.choice(lines)
                return regel
```

I was wondering how I could get the line number (with that I mean the 6th line for example in the .txt will return 6 instead of the word that's on that line).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate a list of integers that has the same length as your lines, and use random choice on this:

```
def randomline(self, file1):
    with open(file1) as f:
        lines = f.readlines()

        indices = range(len(lines)) 
        index = random.choice(indices)

        return index, lines[index]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use enumerate to generate tuples of line number and content and return both:

```
import random

def randomline(file1):
        with open(file1) as f:
            nums_and_lines = list((num, line) for num, line in enumerate(f))
            regel = random.choice(nums_and_lines)
            return regel

randomline('test.py')
# (7, '        metavar="filename\\(s\\)",\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to know is how many lines you have in your file, and then you can use the random function to get a random number between 1 and the number of lines in your file.

```
import random

def random_line(file_name):
    return random.randint(1, sum(1 for line in open(file_name)))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about what's actually on the lines, you're just choosing a random number between 1 and number of lines in the file.

Also, there is no need for the function to be a class method because it doesn't use any attributes of the class.

```
import random

def randomline(file1):
    with open(file1) as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        return random.randint(1, len(lines))
```